# Asymmetrical flat pedals: why and how to use?

Tags: pedals, pedals-flat

My bike has trapezoidal flat pedals, similar to the ones pictured below. One edge is smaller than the other.

[image: Two loose bike pedals, trapezoidal shaped, such that the front edge is smaller than the back edge]

Since they're just flat pedals, there is no reliable way to favour one position over another — leading with the smaller edge or with the larger edge.

So why are these pedals asymmetrical and how are they to be used?

Comment: I'd not expect any "special feature" from entry level urban pedals with unconventional design, other than looks. Otherwise, the asymmetry should cause the pedal to always be with the large side down when pedals are resting (like dual SPD/flat pedals), so if you approach from front or rear, you'll have the large side front/rear, but again, there shouldn't be any functional difference.

Comment: @Renaud not even that, since the difference isn't pronounced enough or its bearings not smooth enough to make the pedals always hang same side down when not in use.